# GDB debugging breaks without breakpoints with Infineon XMC4800 MCU and Segger

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, clion, segger-jlink

We have a EtherCAT project and for this we are using the XMC4800 MCU from Infineon. I was working in Dave (their IDE) first, but because it is not CMAKE based I ran into issues with adding re-usable libs (we use CPM for this).

So I decided to try and create a CMakeLists.txt file for the Dave project and see if I could open/compile the project in CLion.

After a couple of hours I was able to get the project building in CLion. (I just open Dave to make changes to the Hardware settings)

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

# specify cross compilers and tools
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# project settings
project(L16_V2 C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)


add_compile_definitions(XMC4800_F144x2048)
add_compile_options(-O0 -lm -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall 
    -std=gnu99 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wa,-adhlns="$@.lst" -pipe -c 
    -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -g -gdwarf-2)

# uncomment to mitigate c++17 absolute addresses warnings
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-register")

if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast -g)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for size")
    add_compile_options(-Os)
else ()
    message(STATUS "Minimal optimization, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Og -g)
endif ()

include_directories(SSC/Src Dave/Generated/PWM 
    Dave/Generated/SYSTIMER Dave/Generated/INTERRUPT 
    Dave/Generated/PIN_INTERRUPT Dave/Generated/SPI_MASTER 
    Dave/Generated/ECAT_SSC Dave/Generated/GLOBAL_CCU4 
    Dave/Generated/GLOBAL_CCU8 Dave/Generated/EVENT_DETECTOR 
    Dave/Generated/EVENT_GENERATOR Dave/Generated/E_EEPROM_XMC4 
    Dave/Generated/GLOBAL_ADC Dave/Generated/ADC_MEASUREMENT 
    Dave/Generated/BUS_IO Dave/Generated/CLOCK_XMC4 
    Dave/Generated/CPU_CTRL_XMC4 Dave/Generated/DIGITAL_IO Startup 
    Dave/Generated Libraries/CMSIS/Include 
    Libraries/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include 
    Libraries/XMCLib/inc SSC/Src)

add_definitions(-DXMC4800_F144x2048 -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
    -Wall -std=gnu99 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wa,-adhlns="$@.lst" 
    -pipe -c -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m4 
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -g -gdwarf-2)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} 
    "Dave/Generated/*.c" "Startup/*.*" "Libraries/*.c" 
    "SSC/Src/*.c")

set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linker_script_IAP.ld)

add_link_options(-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,
    -Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map)

add_link_options(-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

add_link_options(-nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections 
    -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -mfloat-abi=softfp 
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -g -gdwarf-2)


SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-D_DEBUG")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES} main.c lamp.c PID.c 
    firmwareupdate_SSC.c firmwareupdate_SSC.h 
    flashprog.c ad5328.c ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf m)

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)


add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE}
    Building ${BIN_FILE}")
```

I then setup the "Embedded GDB Server" debug target in combination with a Segger J-link Plus (SWD)

This uploads the compiled application and the target starts running fine. (I make it blink a LED)

The issue is that when I enable break-points it does not break on the breakpoints that I place, but it just breaks at completely other locations. (in my case on the first line of an int handler)

When I debug with the same setup in Dave it works fine.

I tried with both the bundled GDB as with the GNU GDB, it makes no difference

It could be related that this project uses a bootloader (a separate project that I build and flash from Dave)

this is the used Linker script:

```
/**
 * @file XMC4800x2048.ld
 * @date 2019-08-02
 *
 * @cond
 *********************************************************************************************************************
 * Linker file for the GNU C Compiler v1.2
 * Supported devices: XMC4800-E196x2048
 *                    XMC4800-F144x2048
 *                    XMC4800-F100x2048
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2015-2019, Infineon Technologies AG
 * All rights reserved.                        
 *                                             
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,are permitted provided that the 
 * following conditions are met:   
 *                                                                              
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following 
 * disclaimer.                        
 * 
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following 
 * disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.                       
 * 
 * Neither the name of the copyright holders nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote 
 * products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.                                           
 *                                                                              
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, 
 * INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE  
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE  FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, 
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR  
 * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, 
 * WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                                                  
 *                                                                              
 * To improve the quality of the software, users are encouraged to share modifications, enhancements or bug fixes with 
 * Infineon Technologies AG dave@infineon.com).                                                          
 *********************************************************************************************************************
 *
 * Change History
 * --------------
 *
 * 2015-05-22:
 *     - Initial version
 *
 * 2015-07-13:
 *     - Updates from ARM template for C++ and fixes for GCC 4.9q2
 * 
 * 2016-03-08:
 *     - Fix size of BSS and DATA sections to be multiple of 4
 *     - Add assertion to check that region SRAM_combined does not overflowed no_init section  
 *             
 * 2019-08-02
 *     - Fix size of flash reserved to application to 896KB     
 * 
 * @endcond 
 *
 */

OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

stack_size = DEFINED(stack_size) ? stack_size : 2048;
no_init_size = 64;

MEMORY
{
  FLASH_0_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
  FLASH_0_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
  FLASH_1_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08020000, LENGTH = 0x000E0000
  FLASH_1_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C020000, LENGTH = 0x000E0000
  PSRAM_1(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFE8000, LENGTH = 0x18000
  DSRAM_1_system(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x20000
  DSRAM_2_comm(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20020000, LENGTH = 0x20000
  SRAM_combined(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFE8000, LENGTH = 0x00058000
}

SECTIONS
{
  /* TEXT section */

  .text : ALIGN (4)
  {
    sText = .;
    KEEP(*(.reset));
    *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*);

    /* C++ Support */
    KEEP(*(.init))
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    /* .ctors */
    *crtbegin.o(.ctors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.ctors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .ctors)
    *(SORT(.ctors.*))
    *(.ctors)

    /* .dtors */
    *crtbegin.o(.dtors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.dtors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .dtors)
    *(SORT(.dtors.*))
    *(.dtors)

    *(.rodata .rodata.*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
        
  } > FLASH_1_cached AT > FLASH_1_uncached

  .eh_frame_hdr : ALIGN (4)
  {
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame_hdr))
  } > FLASH_1_cached AT > FLASH_1_uncached
  
  .eh_frame : ALIGN (4)
  {
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame))
  } > FLASH_1_cached AT > FLASH_1_uncached

  /* Exception handling, exidx needs a dedicated section */
  .ARM.extab : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  } > FLASH_1_cached AT > FLASH_1_uncached

  . = ALIGN(4);
  __exidx_start = .;
  .ARM.exidx : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
  } > FLASH_1_cached AT > FLASH_1_uncached
  __exidx_end = .;
  . = ALIGN(4);
    
    /* DSRAM layout (Lowest to highest)*/
  Stack (NOLOAD) : 
  {
    __stack_start = .;
    . = . + stack_size;
    __stack_end = .;
    __initial_sp = .;
  } > SRAM_combined

  /* functions with __attribute__((section(".ram_code"))) */
  .ram_code :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */        
    __ram_code_start = .;
    *(.ram_code)
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */
    __ram_code_end = .;
  } > SRAM_combined AT > FLASH_1_uncached
  __ram_code_load = LOADADDR (.ram_code);
  __ram_code_size = __ram_code_end - __ram_code_start;

  /* Standard DATA and user defined DATA/BSS/CONST sections */
  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */        
    __data_start = .;
    *(vtable)        
    * (.data);
    * (.data*);
    *(*.data);
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
      
    . = ALIGN(4);
    /* preinit data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    /* init data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.init_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    /* finit data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.fini_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */
    __data_end = .;
  } > SRAM_combined AT > FLASH_1_uncached
  __data_load = LOADADDR (.data);
  __data_size = __data_end - __data_start;
        
  /* BSS section */
  .bss (NOLOAD) : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */        
    __bss_start = .;
    * (.bss);
    * (.bss*);
    * (COMMON);
    *(.gnu.linkonce.b*)
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */
    __bss_end = .;
  } > SRAM_combined
  __bss_size = __bss_end - __bss_start;

  /* Shift location counter, so that ETH_RAM and USB_RAM are located above DSRAM_1_system */    
  __shift_loc =  (__bss_end >= ORIGIN(DSRAM_1_system)) ? 0 : (ORIGIN(DSRAM_1_system) - __bss_end);

  USB_RAM  (__bss_end + __shift_loc) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */        
    USB_RAM_start = .;
    *(USB_RAM)
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */
    USB_RAM_end = .;
  } > SRAM_combined
  USB_RAM_size = USB_RAM_end - USB_RAM_start;

  ETH_RAM (USB_RAM_end) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */        
    ETH_RAM_start = .;
    *(ETH_RAM)
    . = ALIGN(4); /* section size must be multiply of 4 */
    ETH_RAM_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    Heap_Bank1_Start = .;
  } > SRAM_combined
  ETH_RAM_size = ETH_RAM_end - ETH_RAM_start;

  /* .no_init section contains chipid, SystemCoreClock and trimming data. See system.c file*/
  .no_init ORIGIN(SRAM_combined) + LENGTH(SRAM_combined) - no_init_size (NOLOAD) : 
  {
    Heap_Bank1_End = .;
    * (.no_init);
  } > SRAM_combined

  /* Heap - Bank1*/
  Heap_Bank1_Size  = Heap_Bank1_End - Heap_Bank1_Start;

  ASSERT(Heap_Bank1_Start <= Heap_Bank1_End, "region SRAM_combined overflowed no_init section")

  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.comment)
  }

  .stab   0 (NOLOAD) : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr  0 (NOLOAD) : { *(.stabstr) }

  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug        0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line       0 : { *(.line) }

  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo    0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames    0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }

  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges    0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames   0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  .debug_pubtypes   0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }

  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo    0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }

  /* DWARF 2.1 */
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }

  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames  0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames  0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames  0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames   0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }

  /* Build attributes */
  .build_attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

EDIT:

I found this in the docs for the EtherCAT example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also they mention this:

> Inside
> the linker file the start address of your
> application is defined
> The
> default linker file of DAVE projects defines
> the location of the vector table and
> program data to the flash start address
> 0x0C000000
> To
> reserve space for EEPROM emulation the
> ECAT_SSC APP used inside your project ,
> overwrites this default linker file with every
> code generation to remap the program data
> start address
> 0x0C000000 vector table
> 0x0C020000 program data
> This
> setting does not match to flash partitioning
> used for this example , because the vector table
> overlaps with the bootloader partition
> Instead
> , the following setting is needed
> 0x0C020000
> vector table + program data

Could that have something todo with my issue?

Comment: Don't you think you should add newlines to your cmake code to make it readable?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I did not know it was allowed; you mean I can for example break the "add_compile_options(" line into multiple lines?

Comment: Yes you can `add_compile_optoins(\n one option \n another option \n )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.
After digging into the settings of the Dave project I copied the exact command line parameters for the GDB server from Dave into CLion and from then on the debugging worked as it should.

```
-if swd -device XMC4800-F144x2048 -endian little -speed auto -port 2331 -swoport 2332 -telnetport 2333 -vd -ir -localhostonly 1 -singlerun -strict -timeout 0
```